# How can I prove that this function is periodic :

Tags: functional-analysis, periodic-functions

I know that a periodic function satisfies $F(x+a)=F(x)$

> $y=\left\lfloor\frac{\sin x}x\right\rfloor$

And the period of this fuction is $2\pi$  But putting $f(x+2\pi)$ I can't evaluate denominator inside the  greatest integer function
So how can I prove this function periodic?

Comment: Why do you think the function has period $2\pi$? That's the period of $\sin x$, but that isn't your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any single variable function to be periodic,

$$ f(x) = f(x+ \lambda)$$

should be strictly satisfied. Just having (at least) two sequence of its roots in arithmetic progression is not enough.

Comment: Ok that means that this function cannot be said periodic It just follows a pattern..

Comment: Yes, it cannot be said to be periodic. Even the roots of maxima/minima $\tan x = x $ are not periodic.

Answer (score 3):

**The result is wrong**

First of all you have an issue to deal with at $0$.

Second $y$ is equal to zero on $I=(-\pi, \pi)\setminus \{0\}$. And there is no other translated subset of $I$ in $\mathbb R$ on which $y$ takes such value.